How can i restore an Azure SQL Database?
I have a bacpac file and am trying to restore. Now this file is about 11g compressed so it a 130G database. Or should i create a .bak full backup ?
I have tried Azure restore , I have tried powershell , I have tried sqlpackage , I have tried SSMS and nothing seems to work , I am getting some memory error or process cant be completed error.
Surely if we can backup to bacpac we can restore .
How can i do this ? any help would be appreciated.
UPDATE:
let "randomIdentifier=$RANDOM*$RANDOM"
location="East US"
resourceGroup="msdocs-azuresql-rg-$randomIdentifier"
tag="backup-database"
server="msdocs-azuresql-server-$randomIdentifier"
database="msdocsazuresqldb$randomIdentifier"
login="azureuser"
password="Pa$$w0rD-$randomIdentifier"
storage="msdocsazuresql$randomIdentifier"
container="msdocs-azuresql-container-$randomIdentifier"
bacpac="backup.bacpac"

az sql db export --admin-password $password --admin-user $login -- 
storage-key $key --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri 
"https://$storage.blob.core.windows.net/$container/$bacpac" --name 
$database --resource-group $resourceGroup --server $server


If you're exporting to blob storage, the maximum size of a BACPAC file is 200 GB. To archive a larger BACPAC file, export to local storage with SqlPackage. BACPACs are not intended to be used for backup and restore operations. Azure automatically creates backups for every user database. For automating the same, you can use Azure Automation.

My suggestion about this topic is to avoid importing bacpacs directly to Azure SQL. Restore the bacpac to its original SQL Server instance then use the Data Migration Assistant tool to perform an assessment first and verify there are no incompatibilities with Azure SQL on that database, if no incompatibilities exist the same tool can do the migration of the database for you. This is the easiest method to move a database to Azure SQL without the waste of time and the surprises that involve the use of bacpacs.

So your suggesting no bacpac , no backup ? I have offline bacpac files that i want to restore though , does the migration tool do that ?  The process is i have a backup offline and i want to restore , surely its possible

No the DMA tool does not do import from bacpacs. I suspect the bacpac has incompatibilities with Azure SQL that you are not aware of. So restore the bacpac to the original SQL Server on-premises and perform the assessment with the DMA tool, solve the incompatibilities and then you can create a new bacpac without incompatibilities or use the DMA tool to migrate the database.

Thats the problem i cant restore to the original server , it gives errors as above. So do i perform a new backup ? If so whats the best way to do a back up using az cli ? I need to automate the process

I have updated the question to show how i export the database to a bacpac in azure storage account

When you try to import the bacpac do you receive any error from Azure? See at the Azure SQL logical server level import/export history. What is the reason you find in the details?

I tried to import from Azure Data Studio and now get this error :    Import bacpac: Data plan execution failed with message One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The database 'TestDBNEW' has reached its size quota. Partition or delete data, drop indexes, or consult the documentation for possible resolutions.)) . Is there any setting i can change in Azure to increase the quota ?

Probably the database has a size greater than the limit for the target Azure SQL service tier. Use premium tiers as Azure SQL target.

I have the bacpac in the storage account and when i say to restore , I select the Premium , is that correct. I checked the db , it has a max size of 300 G , I selected a max size of 400 G ?

P6 has a limit of 1 TB. If the database is bigger choose P11 or P15.

I have tried that and still get the error  :   The ImportExport operation with Request Id '' failed due to 'The ImportExport operation with Request Id '' failed due to 'The host process exceeded its memory allowance. Retries will not be successful. Please use SSMS or SqlPackage to complete the operation.'.'. (Code: ImportExportJobError). I have tried SSMS and SqlPackage no luck.   Any suggestions on this ?

should i backup the db to anther format ?

That is why I do not recommend using bacpacs. One can spent days trying to restore a bacpac. Instead of trying a different way of creating a bacpac of an existing database, my suggestion is to use the DMA tool and let the tool migrate the database for you.

So the DMA tool. Will it serve my purposes .. 1.Backup a Azure sql db ,2 . save off line 3. Restore the azure sql db ?

Also when i try to import from Azure it says on the portal when selecting the database from storage account that   "Storage (Premium not supported)" ?

Create a standard storage account. Premium Azure Storage is not supported on Export/Import operations.

Can you please out line what i need to do with some steps as i am very new to all of this , thanks

Let me know if this tutorial helps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell

A Standard Storage Account or General Purpose will do the trick for you. New-AzStorageAccount -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Type Standard_RAGRS -Location $locationName

at the moment i just drop my bacpac file into a storage account in Azure that i created and try to do the restore as above. So what your saying is to create a storage account using your command above "New-AzStorageCoount" drop the file in there and try to run my script ?

I have tried your link but get the error:    A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
*** A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

Then it says:    A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.  I mean it would be able to do the first 20 tables if it was inaccessible ?

This process is becoming painful and annoying as i cant even import a bacpac file ?

I was thinking , is there a way i cant split the file and import small chunks at a time ?

No to my knowledge.

ok so what now ... do i look into the DMA tool ? Does it do backup and restore  as i have never used it ?

Follow the tutorial I provided you on my answer. See the words "Assessment" and "migration" are hyperlink to pages of Microsoft documentation with step-by-step instructions.

I have followed the tutorial and no difference

Will you consider do some sharding with this big database? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-scale-introduction?view=azuresql before migrating it to Azure SQL or Azure SQL Managed Instance?

@Melissa. Geetha is saying this "I sent an email to the mail id but since yesterday i am keep getting mail delivery failure
I need Subscription id can you please share with me the same." Please send her email from a Microsoft Office inbox/ Or send me your subscription ID

You have sent me an email and received fine. Is she typing the correct email , as i have checked spam as well.

@Melissa Please send her an e-mail with your subscription ID.
